# Group array with lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have an array

```
var arrList = [{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe1" },
{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe2" },
{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe3" } ]
```

I want to transform this array and want output like below

```
{
"a@mailinator.com": [{
    "email": "a@mailinator.com",
    "pname": ["john doe1", "john doe2", "john doe3"]
}]
}
```

I have tried with lodash below but no success

```
arrList = _.uniqBy(arrList, "email", "pname")
result = _.chain(arrList).groupBy('email').value('')
```

in the array multiple different email presents, we need to group by email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy), and then [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) the grouped objects to the requested form:

```js
var arrList = [{"email":"a@mailinator.com","pname":"john doe1"},{"email":"a@mailinator.com","pname":"john doe2"},{"email":"a@mailinator.com","pname":"john doe3"}];

var result = _(arrList)
  .groupBy('email')
  .map((v, email) => ({
    email,
    pname: _.map(v, 'pname')
  }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_.chain` and `_.groupBy` and create an array as per your requirement.

```js
var arrList = [{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe1" },
{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe2" },
{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe3" },
{ 
"email": "b@mailinator.com",
"pname": "b doe2" },
{ 
"email": "b@mailinator.com",
"pname": "b doe3" }]

var result=_.chain(arrList).groupBy("email").map(function(v, i) {
  return {
    email: i,
    pname: _.map(v, 'pname')
  }
}).value();
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use core js solution then try this

```
var arrList = [{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe1" },
{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe2" },
{ 
"email": "a@mailinator.com",
"pname": "john doe3" } ]

var temp = {};

for(var value of arrList){
  temp[value.email]  = temp[value.email]  || [];
  temp[value.email][0]  = temp[value.email][0]  || {};
  temp[value.email][0].pname  = temp[value.email][0].pname  || [];
  temp[value.email][0].email = value.email;
  temp[value.email][0].pname.push(value.pname);
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
```